# the checkbox selecting

Tags: php

how do i have one checkbox selected to show the country i select? Like if two countries select simultaneously, it displays a message.i do not understand it. i tried using this code, but seems its not working.

```
if (isset($_POST[''])) {

      $Asia = $_POST[''];
      foreach($Asia as $Key =>$value) {
     echo $Key. ' = ' . $value . '<br>';
     }`
```

Comment: u mean htmlspecialchars? if not, then how?

Comment: with the html code of your page